# Infinite scroll in landscape LWUIT

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-scroll

While I'm developing an application with the Nokia 2.0 SDK, I've found this bug in my app. 
When the device is in Portrait mode, the Form's scroll works fine but when I change the orientation to Landscape I find that the scroll makes bigger than the info in the page.

How can I solve that?

[image: Portrait mode]
[image: Landscape mode]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it!

I forget to put the layout to the `Form` and it doesn't recalculate the size.

Now it's working! Great!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug in the S40 port. Just detect the orientation change (by overriding Form's size changed) and call setText() again. It will trigger a recalculation of the rows in the text area.

Comment: Then perhaps the guys at Nokia know something. Its possible that this is a native input field even when viewed.